# document.write problem

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
$var = <<<MY_MARKER
<script type="text/javascript">
  function asso(){
  showSpoiler("assoluto");
  var x = document.getElementById("assoluto");
  x.write('$str');
 }
</script>
MY_MARKER;

echo $var;
```

The code is in the php section , this is the code valuted from php machine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function asso(){

        showSpoiler("assoluto");

        var x = document.getElementById("assoluto");

        x.write('<div id="log" style="position:absolute;right:0;left:0;top:0;background:black;height:10px;">
<form action="/myblog/index.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login:</legend>
<label><input name="username" size="9" maxlength="15" type="text"  value="username"></label>
<label><input name="password" size="9" maxlength="15" type="password"  value=""></label>
<label><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"></label>
<label><u><a href="index.php?pag=5">Registrati</a></u></label>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
');

    }

</script>
```

The error from console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on the line of x.write(.....);

Comment: where are you making the call to the function from??

Comment: Have you tried chopping off code until you figure out what breaks it specifically?

Comment: @bharath the call function is ...<a href="javascript:asso();">...

Comment: @meder Yes! But nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, multiline strings are not allowed.
Try to remove every "\n" chars:

```
$str = str_replace("\n","",$str);
```

Comment: Same problem , i have just done this before of the script $str = str_replace(array("\t","\n"), "", $str);  I think that the problem is some about javascript write.

Answer (score 0):

So with

```
$str = str_replace(array("\t","\n","\r"), "", $str);
```

and

x.innerHTML = '$str';